# Are there any studies of methylation status in case of proper B12 complementation in vegans/vegetarians?

Tags: health, nutrition, b12, scientific-studies, public-health

I'm trying to look for scientific studies that study the impact of careful vegetarianism/veganism on DNA methylation at the locus level (meQTL study).

The closest I could find was [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16197315), that proves that there is no massive demethylation in vegetarian. But it only looks at a global level, moreover, a lot of the tested vegetarian are B12 defficient, so the "careful" part is not checked either.

Are there more precise studies, peer reviewed or not, that look at the impact of vegetarianism/veganism on methylation, at le locus level, in the case of proper B12 consumption?

Comment: I am not sure from your question what you are looking for, but in the study you cited " from our data no interaction between vegetarian lifestyle and DNA methylation could be determined" . What more do you want ?

Comment: @Panther, the study showed that there were no significant difference in the global levels of methylations, but did not study if the methylation status of specific loci was affected by regime. So in other terms, an meQTL study on veg*nism

Comment: Hmm that is sounding highly specialized almost a PHD thesis. I would be interested if you found anything but I do t know any resource. Thanks for updating what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, it is PhD thesis (or above) level, plus it would require a significant budget. But it seems curious to me that no study have been on this topic (hell I know someone doing this on the effects of meditation !)

Comment: This is probably off-topic, should probably be in https://biology.stackexchange.com/